Modelling extreme rainfall using the Maximum Entropy method in R
I have a dataset with daily rainfall dataset from a meteorological station during the period of 2006 through 2021. The data is stored in a CSV file (here).
A demonstration of how it looks:

After importing this dataset I filter it to include only non-zero rainfall values
# Load the required libraries
library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)
library(extRemes)
library(lubridate)
library(fitdistrplus)
# library(openxlsx) 
# library(evd)

options(scipen = 999) # options(scipen = 0)

# Read the Rainfall Data CSV file
RainfallData <- read.csv("RainfallData.csv", sep = ";", header = TRUE, dec = ",")

# Format the DATE column
RainfallData$DATE <- as.Date(RainfallData$DATE, format = '%d/%m/%Y')

# Clean up the data by removing the first column
RainfallData <- RainfallData[,-1]
dim(RainfallData)
names(RainfallData)[2] <- 'Rain'

# Add three additional columns to the data frame
RainfallData <- RainfallData %>% 
  mutate(DATE = ymd(DATE)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(DATE), list(year = year, month = month, day = day))

# Filter data to include only non-zero rainfall values
non_zero_rain <- RainfallData$Rain[RainfallData$Rain > 0]

to fit a probability distribution (e.g. Gamma, GEV etc.). Fitting using MLE is straightforward as I used the fitdist() and fevd():
#-------------------------------------#
# Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) #
#-------------------------------------#

# Fit Gamma distributions to the non-zero rainfall data using MLE
fitGamma <- fitdist(non_zero_rain, distr = "gamma", method = "mle")
summary(fitGamma)

# Fit GEV distributions to the non-zero rainfall data using MLE
fitGEV <- fevd(non_zero_rain, type = "GEV", method = "MLE")

## Assign the summary of an fevd object to a variable
summaryGEV <- summary(fitGEV, silent = TRUE)
summaryGEV$par
summaryGEV$se.theta
summaryGEV$AIC

Then I implement POME like
#-------------------------------------#
# Principle of Maximum Entropy (POME) #
#-------------------------------------#

# Step 1: Define the GEV PDF

GEV_pdf <- function(x, mu, sigma, k) {
  z <- (x - mu) / sigma
  term <- (1 + k * z)
  if (sigma <= 0 || any(term <= 0)) {
    return(NA)  # Return NA if any values are invalid
  }
  
  if (k != 0) {
    return ((1 / sigma) * exp(-term^(-1/k)) * term^(-(1 + (1 / k))))
  } else {
    return ((1 / sigma) * exp(-z - exp(-z)))
  }
}

# Step 2: Define the entropy function with finite checks
entropy <- function(mu, sigma, k, data) {
  f_values <- sapply(data, function(x) GEV_pdf(x, mu, sigma, k))
  
  # Check for non-finite values in the entropy calculation
  if (any(!is.finite(f_values))) {
    return(Inf)  # Return Inf to avoid invalid entropy calculation
  }
  
  entropy_value <- -mean(log(f_values))
  return(entropy_value)
}

# Step 3: Define the constraints
# Assume we have mean and variance constraints:
mean_constraint <- function(mu, sigma, k, data) {
  predicted_mean <- mean(sapply(data, function(x) GEV_pdf(x, mu, sigma, k)))
  return(predicted_mean)
}

variance_constraint <- function(mu, sigma, k, data) {
  predicted_variance <- var(sapply(data, function(x) GEV_pdf(x, mu, sigma, k)))
  return(predicted_variance)
}

# Step 4: Set up the optimization function
optimize_gev <- function(data) {
  # Initial guesses for mu, sigma, k
  initial_params <- c(mu = mean(data), sigma = sd(data), k = 0.1)
  
  # Define the objective function
  objective_fn <- function(params) {
    mu <- params[1]
    sigma <- params[2]
    k <- params[3]
    ent <- entropy(mu, sigma, k, data)
    
    # Debugging print to monitor each step
    cat("Params:", params, "Entropy:", ent, "\n")
    
    return(ent)
  }
  
  # Use optim to minimize
  result <- optim(
    par = initial_params,
    fn = objective_fn,
    method = "L-BFGS-B",  # Box constraints method
    lower = c(0, 0, 0),  # sigma > 0 constraint
    upper = c(Inf, Inf, 100),
    control = list(fnscale = -1)
  )
  
  return(result$par)  # Return optimized parameters
}

# Ensure non_zero_rain is finite
non_zero_rain <- non_zero_rain[is.finite(non_zero_rain)]

# non_zero_rain` is our vector of rainfall
GEV_params <- optimize_gev(non_zero_rain)
print(GEV_params)

which fails with the error message
Params: 7.289688 15.99324 0.1 Entropy: 3.94637 
Params: 7.290688 15.99324 0.1 Entropy: 3.946378 
Params: 7.288688 15.99324 0.1 Entropy: 3.946361 
Params: 7.289688 15.99424 0.1 Entropy: 3.946415 
Params: 7.289688 15.99224 0.1 Entropy: 3.946324 
Params: 7.289688 15.99324 0.101 Entropy: 3.946112 
Params: 7.289688 15.99324 0.099 Entropy: 3.946628 
Params: 7.298613 16.03863 -0.157942 Entropy: Inf 
Error in optim(par = initial_params, fn = objective_fn, method = "L-BFGS-B",  : 
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

Also the parameter estimates of POME are nowhere close to the MLE results. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Appendix
# Functions to plot rainfall data
    
    createTimeSeriesPlot <- function(RainfallData) {
      plot(
        RainfallData$DATE, 
        RainfallData$Rain, 
        type = "l", 
        xlab = "Year", 
        ylab = "Rainfall (mm)", 
        main = "Trend in Daily Rainfall (mm)",
        xaxt = "n",  # Disable the default x-axis initially
        font.lab = 2  # Bold x and y axis titles
      )
    
      # Add the custom x-axis with more frequent labels (e.g., yearly)
      axis(1, at = seq(from = min(RainfallData$DATE),
                       to = max(RainfallData$DATE),
                       by = "year"),
           format(seq(from = min(RainfallData$DATE),
                      to = max(RainfallData$DATE),
                      by = "year"), "%Y"))
    }
    
    createTimeSeriesPlot(RainfallData)
      
      # Data frame to store summary statistics
      DescStats_table <- data.frame(
        Statistic = c("Mean", "Standard deviation", "Skewness", "Kurtosis", "Minimum", "1st Quartile", "Median", "3rd Quartile", "Maximum")
      )
      
      # Extract statistics using psych::describe
      stats <- psych::describe(RainfallData$Rain)
      stats$Q1 <- summary(RainfallData$Rain)[[2]]
      stats$Q3 <- summary(RainfallData$Rain)[[5]]
      
      # Store relevant summary statistics into the table
      DescStats_table[, 2] <- c(
        stats$mean,
        stats$sd,
        stats$skew,
        stats$kurtosis,
        stats$min,
        stats$Q1,
        stats$median,
        stats$Q3,
        stats$max
      )
      
    # View summary statistics
    print(DescStats_table)

    plot(fitGamma)

    plot(fitGEV)
    plot(fitGEV, type = "probprob", main = "PP Plot of Model vs Empirical Probabilities")
    plot(fitGEV, type = "qq", main = "QQ Plot of Model vs Empirical Quantiles")
    plot(fitGEV, type = "qq2", xlab = "Empirical Quantiles", main = "QQ Plot of Model Simulated vs Empirical Quantiles")
    plot(fitGEV, type = "hist", ylim = c(0, 0.12), col = "lightblue", main = "Histogram with model fitted density")
plot(fitGEV, type = "rl", rperiods = c(5, 50, 100))


It looks straightforward to me. You would need to avoid infinite entropy either by replacing with other values or a change of method which handles entropy = Inf?

I would like to suggest to make your question as concise as possible. Typically, that increases the chance of being answered. I think we do not need the plotting code (I already moved it to the Appendix). Probably, it is possible to include just the relevant data. You could try to paste the output of dput(non_zero_rain) as text.

Thanks @Friede for your edits to my post.
I have now changed
`method = "L-BFGS-B",  # Box constraints method
lower = c(0, 0, 0),    # Keep sigma > 0 and restrict k
upper = c(10, 10, 10),`

Now I get this error
Params: 10 3.725496 0 Entropy: 8.33544  Params: 10 0.000000000000001776357 0 Entropy: -32.96421  Params: 10 0.000000000000001776357 0 Entropy: -32.96421  Params: 9.999 0.000000000000001776357 0 Entropy: Inf 
Error in optim(par = initial_params, fn = objective_fn, method = "L-BFGS-B",  :    non-finite finite-difference value [1] 

Ashok, this is all very interesting but I think you need to back up a couple of steps. First of all, create a histogram of the data to which you are applying ML or ME, and study that histogram to get an idea of what reasonable models should look like. Second, set up your fitting procedure to plot a distribution with the fitted parameters on top of the histogram and see how they compare. Finally, try your ML and ME functions on data for which you already know the answer and verify you get the expected result. Only after getting through those steps should you return to the original data.

Thank you, Robert. histogram for the original rainfall showed a strong right-skew in the distribution. I focused on fitting Gamma, Gumbel, Weibull, and GEV distributions, using MLE to compare models via AIC. The GEV distribution emerged as the best fit. Also checked denscomp(), ppcomp(), & qqcomp().
While MLE was straightforward, much of the literature also advocates for applying POME, Currently working to implement the GEV distribution. However, I am encountering an error at the optim stage. If you have any suggestions on resolving this issue, they would be greatly appreciated.
